# maven get multi-module-project jars into one directory

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module project where I build every project with tycho. Everything including the phase "install" works perfectly. Every module results in one artefact which are installed to my local maven repository...about 10 artefacts.

Now, I would like to make maven additionally copy all 10 artefacts to a local directory if the build successes. At the end, when I rebuilt my application, I should only see one directory with all (updated) artefacts.

Btw, how do the big companies get their product out of the maven repository?

Comment: "Btw, how do the big companies get their product out of the maven repos?" They would probably use [Nexus](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/04/why-nexus-for-the-non-programmer/)

Answer (score 3):

You may define an *aggregator* module in your project, that has dependencies on all other projects and then use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to collect all jars

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>copy-libs</id>
           <phase>package</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
              <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
           </configuration>
         </execution>
       </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Of course you can collect resource files like startup scripts etc using the same plugin. Create another execution

```
<execution>
  <id>copy-sh-files</id>
  <phase>package</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/scripts</outputDirectory>
    <includes>bin/*.sh</includes>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

To put that all together into a single zip, you have to create an assembly file in `src/assembly/zip.xml` with that content

```
<assembly>
    <id>zip</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/bin</directory>
            <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.cmd</include>
            </includes>
            <lineEnding>dos</lineEnding>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target/lib</directory>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

and add the `maven-assembly-plugin` to your build plugins

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptor>src/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
    <finalName>yourProjectFinalName</finalName>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>zip-bundle</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

All these configuration are just one way to do it, but it is a good start. Big companies usually have various requirements for their packaging, including installers etc, so there is no one-size-fits-all solution and it's usually quite a process to get to the final solution.

Comment: Wow, ty. Actually, i have my parent pom.xml which lists all my modules and has package-type "pom". If i create an additional aggregator project, i would have to maintain a secondary list of all modules. Isn't it possible, to add just a few lines to my parent pom.xml?

Comment: you can use the https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/ to execute an ant task and copy all the files, but that does not leverage the full power of maven's dependency mechanism, i.e. resolving and collecting all transitive dependencies your require